# Android Studio 4.1 freezes while indexing when the flutter plugin is installed

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have installed Android Studio 4 with flutter plugin, and it was working fine until yesterday. And then Android Studio freezes during Indexing.
I tried installing Android Studio 4.1 and then changing the flutter channel to stable and dev -- still the freezing issue persists. I have tried uninstalling the flutter and dart plugins, and then installing again, but AS freezes while Indexing after restart...

Has anyone encountered this? Which version of flutter plugin works with which version of Android Studio? Thanks.

Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1)
Android Studio 4 / 4.1

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to remove the .dartServer folder, from this [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28466). After this, indexing was able to proceed.